# Uri %20 converter problem when trying to build a HttpRequestMessage - C#

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, uri

I'm trying to build a http request using HttpRequestMessage from .net. The problem is that my URL contains %20 in parameters, and I need to send specifically %20 not space caracter. But to use HttpRequestMessage I have to transform my string URL in URI, and then it converts the %20 in space.

I tried a few changes, using encoders before sending to httpRequestMessage. The strange part is that if I encode a "%" for example, it maintain the %25 value, but for spaces does't not.
[image: example of test]

Example of me testing Uri.ScapeDataString(), look how it keeps the correctly encoding from '['character, but it looses 'space' caracter:
[Example with ScapeDataString](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFLeO.png)

For me this is clearly a problem on Uri conversion.

Comment: so, I don't know if this fixes your problem, but I tend to use `Uri.EscapeDataString()` for percent encoding. That won't do the '+' that your manually replacing. If you need the %20 in the request, then call EscapeDataString again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Austin, I tried using `Uri.EscapeDataString()` before, I agreed that is best than using Replace, but the problem is no on how I build the URL string, is when I tried to transform that string in a URI. 
I will add an image of an example. Take a look on how it keeps the encoding of '[' correctly, but the 'space' not.